# Angular5 reactive forms. change initial form vals AFTER onInit

Tags: angular

The onInit set up the formGroup and formControls in their initial state,
and the onInit is where I do a service call to get a users data, since that is an observable, I cannot reference one until the other is set - and they are both being set in the onInit - no guarantee either will be done sequentially...

here's what I have - but it's not right, the call to the setOptions, tries to set a form that doesn't exist yet. It seems I need to set it AFTER the onInit - so I tried ngAfterComponentInit - that doesn't work either.

```
    export class xComponent implements OnInit {

    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.auth.getUser(this.user)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.user = data;
                    // tried this first - doesn't work
                    // this.setOptions(this.user.role);
                },
                err => {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            );

        this.form = new FormGroup({
            thing: new FormControl(
                {
                    value: this.model.thing,
                    disabled: this.formDisabled,
                }
            )
        });
    }


    // tried this next - yes, I imported 'AfterContentInit', doesn't work
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.setOptions(this.user.role);
    }

    private setOptions(role) {
        switch (role) {
            case 'role1': {
                this.form.get('thing').patchValue(true);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                this.form.get('thing').patchValue(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

OK - to answer the questions below -

I added all these to see what I might be able to use

```
ngAfterContentInit(){console.log( 'ngAfterContentInit' );console.log( this.user );}
ngAfterContentChecked(){console.log( 'ngAfterContentChecked' );console.log( this.user );}
ngAfterViewInit() {console.log( 'ngAfterViewInit' );console.log( this.user );}
ngAfterViewChecked() {console.log( 'ngAfterViewChecked' );console.log( this.user );}
```

and this is what I got: (console log)

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
ngAfterContentInit--- undefined
ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined

ngAfterViewInit--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked--- undefined

ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked--- undefined

ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked--- undefined

ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked--- undefined

ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked--- undefined

ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked--- undefined

ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked--- undefined

ngAfterContentChecked--- undefined
ngAfterViewChecked --- undefined

onInit data {_id: "5a", role: "A", …}

ngAfterContentChecked ---  {_id: "5a", role: "A", …}
ngAfterViewChecked --- {_id: "5a", role: "A", …}
```

I looks like ngAfterContentChecked, ngAfterViewChecked get called 8 times before the init - and after the init they have the data - I suppose I could do an if in there, and set the form once the data arrives...

Comment: use `ngAfterViewInit()` hook.

Comment: @ManojShukla I won't help. He's getting data asynchronously

Comment: @yurzui Maybe I got it. ;) Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Which line it's pointing out in error?? As you have used `this.user.role` two times.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same pattern and it's working fine for me..

I tried using other lifecycle hooks, and it makes no difference there.

The error of `undefined` could mean that your service is not returning you the desired response (or is sending undefined object), that's why it says, cannot read the property `role` of `undefined`, meaning your `data` (or `this.user` say) is undefined and hence property `role` is not available on it.

Try `console.log(data) // or this.user` to see what's coming out.

And your code for setting form values are fine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about calling to build the form from inside your subscription and **then** set the options? So something in the line of:

```ts
.subscribe(
   data => {
     this.user = data;
     this.buildForm(this.user.role);
   },

// ...

buildForm(role) {
  this.form = new FormGroup({...});

  switch (role) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This then of course requires that you set a condition in the template, as the form is built at later time than in `OnInit`.

Comment: That might work - I'll have to try it and let you know